# Sublinear functional and norm.

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed linear space. Let $C$ be a convex absorbing subset of $X.$ Define the function $p_C : X \longrightarrow \Bbb R_{+}$ by $p_C (x) = \inf \left \{t \gt 0\ |\ x \in tC \right \}.$ Then I have proved that $p_C$ is a sublinear functional. Can $p_C$ be a norm on $X\ $? It is clear that $p_C (0) = 0.$ What about the converse? Suppose $p_C(x) = 0.$ Can we say that $x = 0\ $?

Can anybody please help me in this regard? Thanks for your time.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional#Algebraic_properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$p_C$ is  a norm if $C$ is bounded. $C=X$ is convex and absorbing but $p_C(x)=0$ for all $x \in X$ in this case!

Suppose $C$ is bounded and $p_C(x)=0$. Then theer exists a sequence $(t_n)$ decreasing to $0$ such that $x \in t_nC$ for all $n$. Hence, $\|x\| \leq t_n M$ where $M=\sup \{\|y\|: y \in C\}$. Hence $x=0$.

Comment: That means if $C$ contains a subspace of $X$ then $C$ is no longer a norm. Am I right sir? But for this I think the converse also has to hold.

Comment: If $C$ is a subspace then it is unbounded and $p_C$ is not a  norm.

Comment: But you only prove the forward implication. You didn't mention the converse.

Comment: If $C$ is a subspace then $p_C(x)=0$ for all $x \in C$.